Hard combinatorics related to partition

Let $n$ be a fixed number. Consider every pair of natural sequences $A$ and $B$ indexed from one satisfying $A[i] \ge A[i+1]$ ,$B[i] \ge B[i+1]$ and $\sum (A[i]+B[i]) = n$.
Prove that the two following quantities are equal: (1) number of pairs of sequences satisfying $B[i] = i$ for some $i$; (2) number of pairs of sequences with $B[1] > A[1]$

In an attempt of solving this one I tried doing some bijection by flipping young tabulae without much success. There is also a bijection between pairs of sequences for smaller $n$ and $B$ sequences satisfying (2) by cutting along the dufree square. This also helped me build two generating functions for both quantities namely:
$$\sum_{i=1} x^{i^2}(1-x^i)\prod^i_{j=1} \frac{1}{(1-x^j)^2}\prod_{k=1} \frac{1}{1-x^k}$$
For the first one by considering the dufree square
$$\sum_{i=1} x^{i}(1-x^i)\prod^i_{j=1} \frac{1}{(1-x^j)^2}$$
By considering the largest entry first.
This is close to all my progress. I would really love if someone can provide a full solution if possible by showing the two functions are equal.
Edit:
Example sequence satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $n=3$:
$A:110$ ;$B:1$
$A:100$ ;$B:2$

Where does this problem come from? Do $A$ and $B$ have fixed lengths? Does $A[i+1]\geq A[i]$hold for all $i$ or just one $i$? In the question, what are you summing over in the summation? In the first condition, for which $i$ do you want $B[i]=i$? For any $i$ or a specific one?

You are looking at all pairs of weakly decreasing sequences so to answer you first question : No. To answer the rest $i$ may vary.

Hmmmm , "Where does this problem come from?" , "to answer you first question : No" ?? More-over , "Do A and B have fixed lengths?" , "i may vary" ?? The Q would do with a little bit of editing for clarity.

The Question is currently nonsensical. (1) Consider $B[i]=i$ , hence $B[1]=1$ , $B[2]=2$ , $B[3]=3$ , okay , that gives $B[1]<B[2]$ , $B[2]<B[3]$. Consider given Condition $B[1]>B[2]$ , $B[2]>B[3]$ : Contradiction. (2) One Bijection is vague while the other Bijection is nonsensical. (3) Too many terms are Contradictory/vague/undefined. (4) Example Sequences should be given.

Oh i am deeply sorry. There should exist only one index $i$ which satisfies this.

How is the sum condition supposed to be interpreted, especially for sequences of difference lengths?

In some sense, all the other elements of the sequences are zero.
